# Automatic logoff

Tags: 10.04, login-screen, session

I had a problem with my Ubuntu 10.04 that automatically log off while working,Even i working with Excel its automatically log off and returned to login screen,i checked it all the power settings and updated all it to never.Also i disabled screen saver.In some forums they are telling that keystroke is enabled in your keyboard thats why your facing this,but i don't know where it is....

I think the problem will be small,but i don't know where the problem is.........

Anybody help me to solve this problem,Awaiting for answer............

Comment: Could you please give more details. The information given does not allow anymore than guessing. Do you mean that the whole screen went black and it restarted the graphical screen as if the computer was started?

Comment: the X logfile might be a good place to begin looking for information; `/var/log/Xorg.1.log`

Comment: I agree with Source Lab. I have experienced same symptoms on two machines with ATI Radeon cards, switched the card out and have both been solid since.

Comment: You mention using Excel...  Are you running Excel under Wine, or by Excel do you mean OpenOffice Calc ?

Answer (score 1):

A Windows machine with the same symptoms turned out to have a bad memory module. If you have a Ubuntu live CD, use it to run a memory check.

Comment: You can run memcheck without the live-cd, just press <kbd>Esc</kbd> right after BIOS and select "Memory test (memtest86+)" from the Grub menu.

Comment: Hi txwikinger,

Ya you are right,while working the graphical screen restarted & turned to as if computer started and prompt for password stage.

Comment: I had also tried the memory check its result will be "no errors".

I don't know where is the problem!!!!

Comment: Awaiting answer.................

Answer (score 1):

You've had an X crash.  Usually when this happens a 'backtrace' will be printed to the end of your /var/log/Xorg.0.log or /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old.  Look in those files for a backtrace.

More information about troubleshooting X crashes is available at http://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Backtracing/.